# Bullets and numbered lists not working in my markdown

Tags: css, markdown, jekyll

I'm setting up a Jekyll portfolio site and I'm working on converting my resume into markdown. I'm having an issue where I'm trying to create bullet points but they are not appearing on my page.

My markdown is the following:

```
### Languages and Technologies

-  Java, SQL, C#.NET, XML, JSON, git, SVN
-  Android Studio, Visual Studio, Microsoft SQL Server, Eclipse, Microsoft Office/Visio/Sharepoint
```

But it shows up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbeL7.jpg). I'm using the [end2end jekyll theme](https://github.com/nandomoreirame/end2end) and running locally to test. I'm not sure if the particular markdown processor I'm using doesn't support bullets or what. It doesn't even work for numbered lists either, if I replace the "-" with "1." I still get the same output. Any ideas? How can I get a bulleted list? I'm thinking this might have to do with the CSS the page is using.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. It looks like `list-style` was set to "none" [in a couple of the .scss files of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQy5z.jpg). I commented them out and lists are working now.